# Django migrations missing way to declare "needed_by"?

Tags: django, dependencies, database-migration, django-south

If you have two apps:

- core_app
- plugin_app

The core does not need the optional plugin.

Up to now we used south and could use `needed_by` if a migration of the plugin needs to run before a migration of the core app.

I could not find something in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/

Related. The old south docs: http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/Dependencies

How to tell the new django migrations to run a plugin migration before a core migration?

Of course I don't want to change the source of the core and add a dependency to the plugin migration. This must not be done, since the core should run without the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`run_before` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/writing-migrations/#controlling-the-order-of-migrations):

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    run_before = [
        ('core_app', '0001_initial'),
    ]
```